# Can I set one config for single and multiple optimization

Tags: requirejs

#### file structure

```
assets/js/
        - build/
        - plugin/
            jquery.min.js
        - src/
            index.js
        config.js
        builds.js
        require.js
```

#### assets/js/src/index.js

```
requirejs(['jquery']);
```

#### assets/js/config.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'plugin/jquery.min'
    }
})
```

If I want to use r.js to optimize the file, just execute `r.js -o config.js name=src/index out=build/index.js`, the r.js will compile a file into `build/index.js` with optimization and dependency, but there will be many files need to compile in the future, so I create a builds.js

#### assets/js/builds.js

```
({
    appDir: 'src',
    dir: 'build',
    mainConfigFile: 'config.js',
    modules: [
        {name: 'index'}
    ]
})
```

If I run `r.js -o builds.js`, I will got wrong path message.

`Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\www\r\build\plugin\jquery.min.js'`

I need to go back to `config.js`, and edit the path relative to `src`.

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    paths: {
        jquery: '../plugin/jquery.min'
    }
})
```

It will work, but is it possible to write one config file for both purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Specify paths again in the build file, relative to /src.

### builds.js

```
({
    appDir: 'src',
    baseUrl: './',
    dir: 'build',
    modules: [
        {name: 'index'}
    ],
    paths: {
        jquery: '../plugin/jquery.min'
    }
})
```

The paths in the build file work differently than in the config file.

The appDir option of /src specifies that all your scripts are located in /src, however your config.js and folder structure have the /plugins outside of /src.

When the jquery path is resolved, the paths in the config.js file are used because the mainConfigFile option is used.

All module paths would need to be redefined in your build file in addition to your config file. This is because all module paths are resolved relative to the baseUrl, which is in relation to the appDir in the build file – this is the confusing bit.

Reference the following r.js example build file. https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js

The official doc on the RequireJS optimizer contains a helpful section about path resolution.
http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#basics

> **Relative path resolution rules:**
>
> In general, if it is a path, it is relative to the build.js file used to hold the build options, or if just using command line arguments, relative to the current working directory. Example of properties that are file paths: **appDir, dir, mainConfigFile, out, wrap.startFile, wrap.endFile**.
>
> For **baseUrl**, it is relative to **appDir**. If no appDir, then baseUrl is relative to the build.js file, or if just using command line arguments, the current working directory.
>
> For **paths** and **packages**, they are relative to baseUrl, just as they are for require.js.

Comment: It's not work `Error: Error: ERROR: module path does not exist: D:/www/requirejs/assets/js/index.js for module named: index. Path is relative to: D:/www/requirejs/assets/js`

Comment: It looks like you restructured your directory -- is your build file now in assets/js instead of src? You'd want to set baseUrl so it's relative to your app directory

Comment: I updated the article to make it more clear, builds.js is with config.js under `assets/js directory`, and I want to compile javascript file in `assets/js/src/` to `assets/js/build/` directory.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my answer. You were on the right track, but the solution is to specify paths in the build file in addition to the config file that are relative to the build file's baseUrl.